# Android Studio:: Unable to locate adb

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm new to Android studio and I have AMD machine, and I have this errors and I have tried everything:

> 9:04 PM   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 68936 above
> FD_SETSIZE (32768)
>
> 9:04 PM   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 68936 above
> FD_SETSIZE (32768)
>
> 9:04 PM   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to
> connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
>
> 9:04 PM   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 69264 above
> FD_SETSIZE (32768)
>
> 9:04 PM   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 69264 above
> FD_SETSIZE (32768)
>
> 9:04 PM   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 69264 above
> FD_SETSIZE (32768)
>
> 9:04 PM   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 69264 above
> FD_SETSIZE (32768)
>
> 9:04 PM   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 69268 above
> FD_SETSIZE (32768)
>
> 9:04 PM   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 69268 above
> FD_SETSIZE (32768)
>
> 9:05 PM   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 70896 above
> FD_SETSIZE (32768)
>
> 9:05 PM   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 70896 above
> FD_SETSIZE (32768)
>
> 9:05 PM   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to
> connect to adb da